# How to enable PHP on LAMPP?

Tags: php, lamp

I installed LAMPP a couple of weeks ago. Everything works fine when it comes to html files, but when I try to open a php file, the browser asks me where to download it. :/

I tried with my php files, and I also made a `test.php` which calls `phpinfo()` with no results. localhost/xampp and localhost/ also ask me for download location.

I added the following line to httpd.conf:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
```

But still no results. What could be wrong?

Comment: **How** did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded the tar file, and uncompressed it on /opt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

LAMPP will not work perfectly on Ubuntu.

You should try

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 apache2-php
```

and then you have a PHP enabled server!

Comment: sudo apt-get install apache2 php5  did the trick :) however apt-get didn't find apache2-php

Comment: How is it possible to use apt-get to install from a tar file

Comment: Why "LAMPP will not work perfectly on Ubuntu."?

Answer (score 1):

First, checking your running PHP (CGI , SuPHP or PHP-FPM?)
Usually done by running the command `php -v`
Then check for `libapache-phpx.x` where `x.x` is your php version.

```
a2enmod phpx.x
service apache2 restart
```

Often, if you've installed php before installing apache, this module will be disabled by default.

**PHP-FPM might need more config instead enable apache2 module.**

Comment: As per my experience with APACHE and PHP, I think you are probably using PHP-CGI and missing the Add-Handler in httpd.conf.